# Python: Substituting variables with functions SymPy

Tags: python, sympy

I'm writing a code where I need to substitute variables of a function with multiple functions.

For example, I have `B=x1**2+x2**2+x3**2` where I need to substitute `x1=cos(x1+x2)`, `x2=sin(x2+x3)` and `x3=x1` so as to get this value: `cos(x1+x2)**2+sin(x2+x3)**2+x1**2`

However, when I do this iteratively like this:

```
for j in range(nvar):
        B=expand(B.subs(x[j],f[j]))
```

where `nvar=3` and x is defined as a list of symbols and f as a list of symbolic functions, at each iteration, `x[j]` from the previous substitution is replaced and gives a wrong answer: `x1**2 + sin(x1 + cos(x1 + sin(x1 + x2)))**2 + cos(x1 + sin(x1 + cos(x1 + sin(x1 + x2))))**2`

How can I perform this substitution simultaneously?

Comment: You can just use another names for your substituted variables, like `x1=cos(y1+y2)`, because mathematically `scipy` gives you the correct expansion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `simultaneous` keyword for subs which was made for cases like this:

```
>>> (x1**2+x2**2+x3**2).subs(dict(x1=cos(x1+x2), x2=sin(x2+x3), x3=x1), simultaneous=True)
x1**2 + sin(x2 + x3)**2 + cos(x1 + x2)**2
```

Or, if x and f contain all instances of replacements you are interested in,

```
>>> reps = dict(zip(x, f))
>>> B = expand(B.subs(reps, simultaneous=True)
```